# How to show all the names in a responsive way using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface

I have an Array of 500 names as follows:

```
var names= ['LongName 1234567890', 'LongName 1234567890', 'LongName 1234567890', 'LongName 1234567890', 'LongName 1234567890', 'LongName 1234567890',...... 'LongName 1234567890', ];
```

I have a blank page with bootstrap setted up on it. I have to show all these names in Horizantal and vertical way (similar to table) in responsive way.

for ex: if It is desktop pc I have to show all these in 7 rows and 14 columns, tablet a bit less in a responsive way. i am very new to Bootstrap or front end development. How I can acheive that ?

I tried creating span tags inside the div. But I am not sure that is rightway of doing it in bootstrap manner.

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pj0cz3n5/

Comment: Some like this  http://jsfiddle.net/pj0cz3n5/1/ ?

Comment: @Danko: Thank you Danko. That is awesome. I am exactly looking like that. But in tablets and mobile devices I can see a lot of empty space on right hand side. How can I use it completely ?

Comment: If you can elaborate an example on bootply to work ... and /or add imgs of the actual and desire layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this it sets each span to 14% of the width reducing the spaces that you have been seeing.

http://jsfiddle.net/pj0cz3n5/4/

```
.row span{
    float:left;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 14%;
}
```

The 14% is nothing more than 100% divided by 7 - giving 7 columns at all times.
You need to modify this for the different widths of devices.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option: http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/pj0cz3n5/19/

If you are able to wrap your names in some Bootstrap classes then you can achieve nice, neat, responsive columns. You would need to tweak the BS class names depending on the actual lengths of your long names.

Typical HTML:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">Long Name 123456788</div>
```